# Microsoft-Graph: Failing to get token from python code: Error SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to call a web API. For that I need a bearer token.

I am using databricks(python) code to first get authenticated over Microsoft AAD. Then get bearer token for my service_user. I Followed the microsoft docs [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-username-password?tabs=python)

But facing problem where it hits our Company server and asking for SSL certificate.

I can't install any certificate. What could be a better way to avoid it. Below is my short code taken from above microsoft and Git repos. but its not working.

Can i get help!

```
clientId = "42xx-xx-xx5f"
authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/"
app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id=clientId, authority=authority)
user = "serviceuser@company.com"
pwd = "password"
scope = "Directory.Read.All"

result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(scopes=[scope], username=user, password=pwd)
print(result)
```

**Got below error**

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mycompany.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /adfs/services/trust/mex (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code uses the `requests` library that relies on the `certifi` package instead of using Linux certificate chain (so [existing instructions doesn't work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/python/import-custom-ca-cert)).  To solve that problem it's better to use [cluster init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) that will install SSL certificate when cluster starts.  Something like this (`requests` and `certifi` are installed by default), just replace `CERT_FILE` with actual path to the `.pem` file with CA certificate:

```sh
CERT_FILE="/dbfs/....."
CERTIFI_HOME="$(python -m certifi 2>/dev/null)"
cat $CERT_FILE >> $CERTIFI_HOME
```